# Get yesterday query from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get queries just for yesterday! With this code, I can get queries for today, but I don't know what should i do to show just yesterday queries:

```
$t_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i', $_TIME - (3596 * 24) );
$twall = $db->super_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as c 
                             FROM dle_photo_post 
                            WHERE date > = '$t_date'
                              AND date < = '$t_date' + INTERVAL 24 HOUR 
                              AND moder = '0' ");

$twall = $twall['c'];
```

Comment: [MySQL Date Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: if u don't wanna help somebody, why did u send this comment?

Comment: He is trying to help you learn where to look for answers instead of just giving a solution. Most people here want to know you have tried to solve the problem instead of just asking for someone else to solve it. See: whathaveyoutried.con

Comment: Maybe try change WHERE clause with just `WHERE date = DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE()- interval 1 day),'%x-%m-%d') AND moder = '0'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c 
FROM dle_photo_post 
WHERE date between 
                date_sub(curdate(), interval 2 day) 
            and date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
    AND moder = '0'
```

Comment: no its not working! my yesterday queris is 2 and day before yesterday was 25, so i need to show 2, but with your code i got 27

Comment: I just edited it, give that a try. My original code did *today*

Comment: sorry, but im not pro with sql, i tried but i could not fix that

Comment: Is there something wrong with the edited code? It should work as it is.

Comment: problem is, with your code i cant show yesterday queries, i dont know why it shows all days except today!